# Sorting a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, sorting

I'm trying to sort the output of this code by size of the file. Currently I have:

```
IFS=!
FILEARRAY=(`find * -printf %f!`)
```

to get all of the file names out of the directory. I've tried piping it all sorts of ways and nothing works. Is it even possible to do like this or do I need to go about getting the file names in my array a different way?

Thanks

Comment: I get `bash: !: event not found` when I try to run that command.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here but to extract the size of the files you might want to use `sed`. to pass it to `sort` or some other sorting utility check out `xargs` which gives you some extra features when piping and might be of some use.

Edit:
If you are trying to sort all of the files in the current directory by size,
somthing like this:

```
find ./ -name "*" | xargs ls -s | sort -n
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
FILEARRAY=$(find * -printf '%s~%f\n' | sort -n | awk -F"~" '{print $2}')
```

This should give you a list of file names sorted by size.

Answer (score 0):

Does not use bash arrays. Also [does not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
find . -type f -printf '%s:%f\n' | sort -t: -n -k1 | cut -d: -f2-
```